# Data reshape (from vector to array) in R

Tags: r

I want you to help me about R code.

I have an object, M(list & array). Like this.

```
object1 <- array(0, c(2,2,2))
M <- list(object1, object1)
```

Then, I want to reshape m(vector) into M structure.

```
m <- c(1:16)
```

When M is list & matrix object, I can use 'relist' function. However, I can't use it to array object. How can I reshape m into M structure??

Comment: `Map(function(new, old){dim(new) <- dim(old); new}, new = relist(m, M), old = M)`

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the dims in `array` and use `relist`

```
lapply(relist(m, skeleton = M), array, dim(object1))
#[[1]]
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8


#[[2]]
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    9   11
#[2,]   10   12

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   13   15
#[2,]   14   16
```

---

Or another option is

```
lapply(setNames(split(m, (seq_along(m)-1) %/% lengths(M)[1]), NULL), array, dim(object1))
#[[1]]
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8


#[[2]]
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    9   11
#[2,]   10   12

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   13   15
#[2,]   14   16
```

NOTE: Both the solutions are one-line solutions